# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, dll

I have developed an application in WPF C# using .Net Framework 4.0 which uses Sqlite database. In order to access [Sqlite] database from C#, System.Data.Sqlite.dll is being used. Things are working fine windows 7, 8 and 10 desktop machines.

But in Microsoft Surface Pro 4, System.Data.Sqlite.dll is failing to load.
Below is the error message being received-

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

While the DLL file is already available at the specified location.

Kindly update.

Comment: Could you pls provide the code you load SQLite dll and  corresponding file structure?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most likely causes is processor mismatch.  You may have compiled your program for "Any" processor and linked to the 32 bit SQLite library.

There are ways to do this properly, but I have usually ended up compiling as x86 and using the 32 bit library to ensure compatibility on some of my customer's older machines, without added complexities.

Comment: Application is running fine on 64 bit WIN-10 desktop machine. But this issue is only occurring in Surface Pro-4 having 64-bit WIN-10.